# Keep my Activty open on notification click?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-task

I have a strange scenario in my application where I want to keep my activity open even though if any notification is clicked. The scenario is I have splash activity that opens the Home Activity and then the OfferActivity(opened through home activity after getting a response). Now I want to remain on the offer activity even after users click on any notification received meanwhile. The problem is all my notification enter into the app through splash screen with intent data and then splash screen pass the data to the home activity which perform the specific action. Please help with your suggestions on the best way to handle it. At the moment I am clearing the notification tray when I opened the offer activity and block the notification display for the moment.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: when your application is running, the callback is coming on `onMessageReceived` right? all you have to do is just create empty `intent` in your `pendingIntent` instead giving it the class name

Comment: yes @AshwiniViolet let me try it.

Comment: @HardikTalaviya sorry man I am not allowed to do so

Comment: check this answer for how to create an empty `pendingIntent` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768626/notification-without-pending-intent

Comment: @AshwiniViolet what about the existing notification I already have. How to deal with them? Your solution is fine for the new coming one.

Comment: without code and exact scenario, we cannot help you much here but you can handle it like whatsapp do. you will need to remove the notification that become irrelevant(notifications have IDs to identity and remove them). i suggest you to explore whatsapp

Comment: it make sense Thanks @AshwiniViolet